finding pattern over years with dplyr and tidyverse
I have to find in my data the following: count the number of letters in words to find distribution of lengths of words and I have to group them by year and find the mean length of word for every year.
My question is fairly similar to the following example and question from the book R for Data Science (2ed) on the babynames mock df: Are there any major trends in the length of babynames over time?
library(tidyverse)
library(babynames)

babynames |>
count(length = str_length(name), wt = n)

I am not sure how to continue to find trends of word length (I have to use mean of the length) over years. I tried the following code below but I think its wrong
babynames |>  
group_by(year) %>% 
count(length = str_length(name), wt = n) %>% 
summarise (
          average_length_perY = mean(length, na.rm = TRUE),
          n = n())


I think I found the solution:
babynames |>   group_by(year) %>%   summarize (average_Namelength_perY = mean(str_length(name), wt = n))

Just a note: To get the weighted mean use weighted.mean(str_length(name), w = n).
